# Prophet Package - Adding holidays to a forecast by Group in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I was reading this Q&A on running prophet by groups in R.
[Using Prophet Package to Predict By Group in Dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820696/using-prophet-package-to-predict-by-group-in-dataframe-in-r/45254762#45254762)

The answers provided are useful, but do not cover the addition of the holidays parameter for the prophet function.

How can I pass the holidays data.frame to the prophet function when running the function by groups?

This is my sample data:

```
# time series df
ds <- as.Date(c('2016-11-01','2016-11-02','2016-11-03','2016-11-04',
        '2016-11-05','2016-11-06','2016-11-07','2016-11-08',
        '2016-11-09','2016-11-10','2016-11-11','2016-11-12',
        '2016-11-13','2016-11-14','2016-11-15','2016-11-16',
        '2016-11-17','2016-11-18','2016-11-19','2016-11-20',
        '2016-11-21','2016-11-22','2016-11-23','2016-11-24',
        '2016-11-25','2016-11-26','2016-11-27','2016-11-28',
        '2016-11-29','2016-11-30',


        '2016-11-01','2016-11-02','2016-11-03','2016-11-04',
        '2016-11-05','2016-11-06','2016-11-07','2016-11-08',
        '2016-11-09','2016-11-10','2016-11-11','2016-11-12',
        '2016-11-13','2016-11-14','2016-11-15','2016-11-16',
        '2016-11-17','2016-11-18','2016-11-19','2016-11-20',
        '2016-11-21','2016-11-22','2016-11-23','2016-11-24',
        '2016-11-25','2016-11-26','2016-11-27','2016-11-28'))


y <-c(15,17,18,19,20,54,67,23,12,34,12,78,34,12,3,45,67,89,12,111,123,112,14,566,345,123,567,56,87,90, 45,23,12,10,21,34,12,45,12,44,87,45,32,67,1,57,87,99,33,234,456,123,89,333,411,232,455,55)

y <- as.numeric(y)

group <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
 "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
 "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
 "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

df <- data.frame(ds,group, y)
df

        ds      group y
1  2016-11-01     A  15
2  2016-11-02     A  17
3  2016-11-03     A  18
4  2016-11-04     A  19
5  2016-11-05     A  20
6  2016-11-06     A  54
7  2016-11-07     A  67
8  2016-11-08     A  23
9  2016-11-09     A  12
10 2016-11-10     A  34
11 2016-11-11     A  12
12 2016-11-12     A  78
13 2016-11-13     A  34
14 2016-11-14     A  12
15 2016-11-15     A   3
16 2016-11-16     A  45
17 2016-11-17     A  67
18 2016-11-18     A  89
19 2016-11-19     A  12
20 2016-11-20     A 111
21 2016-11-21     A 123
22 2016-11-22     A 112
23 2016-11-23     A  14
24 2016-11-24     A 566
25 2016-11-25     A 345
26 2016-11-26     A 123
27 2016-11-27     A 567
28 2016-11-28     A  56
29 2016-11-29     A  87
30 2016-11-30     A  90
31 2016-11-01     B  45
32 2016-11-02     B  23
33 2016-11-03     B  12
34 2016-11-04     B  10
35 2016-11-05     B  21
36 2016-11-06     B  34
37 2016-11-07     B  12
38 2016-11-08     B  45
39 2016-11-09     B  12
40 2016-11-10     B  44
41 2016-11-11     B  87
42 2016-11-12     B  45
43 2016-11-13     B  32
44 2016-11-14     B  67
45 2016-11-15     B   1
46 2016-11-16     B  57
47 2016-11-17     B  87
48 2016-11-18     B  99
49 2016-11-19     B  33
50 2016-11-20     B 234
51 2016-11-21     B 456
52 2016-11-22     B 123
53 2016-11-23     B  89
54 2016-11-24     B 333
55 2016-11-25     B 411
56 2016-11-26     B 232
57 2016-11-27     B 455
58 2016-11-28     B  55

# holidays df
ds <- as.Date(c('2016-11-10','2016-11-23','2016-11-19','2016-11-28'))

group <- c("A","A","B","B")

holiday <- c('holiday_a', 'holiday_b','holiday_c', 'holiday_d')

holidays <- data.frame(ds,group, holiday)

holidays 

      ds      group  holiday
1 2016-11-10     A holiday_a
2 2016-11-23     A holiday_b
3 2016-11-19     B holiday_c
4 2016-11-28     B holiday_d
```

I tried group by the holidays data.frame parameter when passing it to the prophet function, but the output is not correct. All the holidays a,b,b,d are passed to each group, independently by the group in the holidays data.frame; which is incorrect.

```
df %>%  
   group_by(group) %>%
   do(predict(prophet(., holidays = group_by(holidays, group)), 
   make_future_dataframe(prophet(.), periods = 7))) %>%
   select(ds, group, yhat,holiday_a,holiday_b,holiday_c,holiday_d)  %>%
   as.data.frame()  

        ds       group  yhat     holiday_a holiday_b holiday_c  holiday_d
1  2016-11-01     A -94.6419164   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
2  2016-11-02     A -96.5462126   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
3  2016-11-03     A  90.9201486   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
4  2016-11-04     A  11.6291775   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
5  2016-11-05     A -39.6195794   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
6  2016-11-06     A 101.3672497   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
7  2016-11-07     A -27.1164855   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
8  2016-11-08     A -26.1950639   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
9  2016-11-09     A -28.0996817   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
10 2016-11-10     A  72.4524666 -86.91389   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
11 2016-11-11     A  80.0750655   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
12 2016-11-12     A  28.8259872   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
13 2016-11-13     A 169.8124950   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
14 2016-11-14     A  41.3284385   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
15 2016-11-15     A  42.2498601   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
16 2016-11-16     A  40.3452425   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
17 2016-11-17     A 227.8112824   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
18 2016-11-18     A 148.5199899   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
19 2016-11-19     A  45.7585824   0.00000   0.00000 -51.51233    0.00000
20 2016-11-20     A 238.2574195   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
21 2016-11-21     A 109.7733629   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
22 2016-11-22     A 110.6947844   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
23 2016-11-23     A  62.5667545   0.00000 -46.22341   0.00000    0.00000
24 2016-11-24     A 296.2562062   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
25 2016-11-25     A 216.9649135   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
26 2016-11-26     A 165.7158351   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
27 2016-11-27     A 306.7023427   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
28 2016-11-28     A 126.2788594   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -51.93943
29 2016-11-29     A 179.1397075   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
30 2016-11-30     A 177.2350897   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
31 2016-12-01     A 364.7011292   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
32 2016-12-02     A 285.4098366   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
33 2016-12-03     A 234.1607582   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
34 2016-12-04     A 375.1472658   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
35 2016-12-05     A 246.6632091   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
36 2016-12-06     A 247.5846306   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
37 2016-12-07     A 245.6800127   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
38 2016-11-01     B -71.4343718   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
39 2016-11-02     B -77.8417828   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
40 2016-11-03     B   8.7292616   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
41 2016-11-04     B  33.1001674   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
42 2016-11-05     B -27.3674191   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
43 2016-11-06     B  72.5228028   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
44 2016-11-07     B  53.5127980   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
45 2016-11-08     B   6.8424459   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
46 2016-11-09     B   0.4350352   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
47 2016-11-10     B  43.3701494 -43.63593   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
48 2016-11-11     B 111.3769861   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
49 2016-11-12     B  50.9093997   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
50 2016-11-13     B 150.7996217   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
51 2016-11-14     B 131.7896172   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
52 2016-11-15     B  85.1848200   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
53 2016-11-16     B  78.8429644   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
54 2016-11-17     B 165.4795640   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
55 2016-11-18     B 189.9160251   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
56 2016-11-19     B  75.9048249   0.00000   0.00000 -53.60917    0.00000
57 2016-11-20     B 229.4697708   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
58 2016-11-21     B 210.5253213   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
59 2016-11-22     B 163.9205243   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
60 2016-11-23     B 146.5432931   0.00000 -11.03538   0.00000    0.00000
61 2016-11-24     B 244.2152686   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
62 2016-11-25     B 268.6517298   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
63 2016-11-26     B 208.2496985   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
64 2016-11-27     B 308.2054755   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
65 2016-11-28     B 178.5735017   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000 -110.68752
66 2016-11-29     B 242.6562289   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
67 2016-11-30     B 236.3143734   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
68 2016-12-01     B 322.9509732   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
69 2016-12-02     B 347.3874344   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
70 2016-12-03     B 286.9854031   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
71 2016-12-04     B 386.9411801   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
72 2016-12-05     B 367.9967306   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000    0.00000
```

How do I pass the holidays data.frame to the prophet function run by groups to forecast each group with the corresponding holidays?

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer, using map2 purrr function forecasts each group with the corresponding holidays

```
df_nested <- df %>%  
group_by(group) %>%
nest()    

holidays_nested <- holidays %>%  
group_by(group) %>%
nest() %>%
rename(holidays = data)    

df_input <- df_nested %>% left_join(holidays_nested)     

df_input %>%
   mutate(forecast = map2(data, holidays, ~predict(prophet(df = .x, holidays = .y), make_future_dataframe(prophet(df = .x, holidays = .y), periods = 7)))) %>%
   unnest(forecast) %>%
   select(ds, group, yhat,holiday_a,holiday_b,holiday_c,holiday_d)  %>%
   as.data.frame()
```

Thanks for those who looked into the question.

Comment: @Macro Vene I am getting this below error at the end. Error: Column name `holidays` must not be duplicated......or at unnest(forecast) command