# Using R Prophet across multiple groups

Tags: r, time-series, facebook-prophet, prophet

I've used Prophet previously to forecast individual metrics, but I now need to forecast into 2022, using around 3 years of historic data and including multiple groups. I'd rather not create 1000+ forecasts for each possibility, so hoping I can do this within Prophet.

I've read through a [couple of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820696/using-prophet-package-to-predict-by-group-in-dataframe-in-r) on Stackoverflow which work for a singular group, but I have 3 different groups to forecast.

Below I've created a sample table, with dummy Y data showing how the data is formatted:
(Note: There can and will be zero values, but I can exclude them if it'd negatively affect the outputs)

| ds | establishment | category | channel | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | High School | Stationery | Direct | 27 |
| 2020-01-01 | High School | Stationery | Paid Search | 31 |
| 2020-01-01 | High School | Arts | Direct | 47 |
| 2020-01-01 | High School | Arts | Paid Search | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | College | Stationery | Direct | 60 |
| 2020-01-01 | College | Stationery | Paid Search | 35 |
| 2020-01-01 | College | Arts | Direct | 54 |
| 2020-01-01 | College | Arts | Paid Search | 15 |
| 2020-01-02 | High School | Stationery | Direct | 27 |
| 2020-01-02 | High School | Stationery | Paid Search | 31 |
| 2020-01-02 | High School | Arts | Direct | 47 |
| 2020-01-02 | High School | Arts | Paid Search | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | College | Stationery | Direct | 60 |
| 2020-01-02 | College | Stationery | Paid Search | 35 |
| 2020-01-02 | College | Arts | Direct | 54 |
| 2020-01-02 | College | Arts | Paid Search | 15 |
| 2020-01-03 | High School | Stationery | Direct | 27 |
| 2020-01-03 | High School | Stationery | Paid Search | 31 |
| 2020-01-03 | High School | Arts | Direct | 47 |
| 2020-01-03 | High School | Arts | Paid Search | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | College | Stationery | Direct | 60 |
| 2020-01-03 | College | Stationery | Paid Search | 35 |
| 2020-01-03 | College | Arts | Direct | 54 |
| 2020-01-03 | College | Arts | Paid Search | 15 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The following code works for a single group, but I'd like to expand this to include all groups.

```
d1 <- df %>%
  nest(-establishment) %>%
  mutate(m = map(data, prophet)) %>%
  mutate(future = map(m, make_future_dataframe, period = 730)) %>%
  mutate(forecast = map2(m, future, predict))

d <- d1 %>%
  unnest(forecast) %>%
  select(ds, establishmentShortcut, yhat)
```

If anybody can recommend a solution, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Just thought I'd drop a word of caution about using prophet, as described nicely in [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/is-facebooks-prophet-the-time-series-messiah-or-just-a-very-naughty-boy-8b71b136bc8c). If you're aware of this already, I apologize and feel free to ignore!

Answer (score 1):

This is what the fable package is designed to do. There is a fable extension for handling prophet models called `fable.prophet`. Here is an example using the same structure as your data.

```r
library(fable.prophet)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tsibble)

df <- tibble(
    ds = rep(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by="1 day", length=50), rep(8,50)),
    establishment = rep(rep(c("High School","College"), c(4,4)), 50),
    category = rep(rep(c("Stationery","Arts"), c(2,2)), 100),
    channel = rep(c("Direct","Paid Search"), 200),
    y = sample(0:100, 400, replace=TRUE)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=ds, key=c("establishment","category","channel"))

fc <- df %>%
  model(
    prophet = prophet(y),
  ) %>%
  forecast(h=10)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can swap out `prophet()` for any of the other models in the `fable` package. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/ for details.

Comment: This looks very promising Rob, but I'm struggling with the example given.
I'm getting the error:
"Error in prophet(y) : object 'y' not found."

I've tried directly referencing the column, but get an invalid 'pos' argument.

Comment: Use the most recent versions of packages and run the code in a new session. Possibly you have old packages, or perhaps you have clashes with other loaded packages.