# Exclude Weekends in Dot in Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-loops, facebook-prophet

This is a continuation question from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45254762/5893585

I am using the `do` function in `dplyr` within the `prophet` package. When attempting this I want to make a future dataframe with weekends excluded. Below is my current code:

Current dataframe:

```
dataset
          ds     group     y
  2021-12-15         A     5
  2021-12-16         A     6
  2021-12-15         B    10
  2021-12-16         B     7
         etc       etc   etc
```

Prediction

```
library(dplyr)
library(prophet)

data = dataset %>%  
group_by(group) %>%
do(predict(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), 
make_future_dataframe(prophet(.,daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), periods = 14))) %>%
select(ds, group, yhat)
```

How do I rewrite the above code to filter for the `make_future_dataframe` dataset not have weekends?

I want it to looks something like this, however this is not working:

```
data = dataset %>%  
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(predict(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), 
  make_future_dataframe(prophet(.[which(weekdays(.$ds) != 'Saturday' | weekdays(.$ds) != 'Sunday'),],daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), periods = 14))) %>%
  select(ds, group, yhat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could remove weekend days prior to predict:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(weekdays = weekdays(ds)) %>% 
  filter(weekdays != "Saturday" & weekdays != "Sunday") %>% 
  do(predict(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), 
  filter(make_future_dataframe(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), periods = 14), weekdays(ds) != "Saturday" & weekdays(ds) != "Sunday"))) %>%
  select(ds, group, yhat)
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the output still includes weekend data. Any idea why this would still be the case?

Comment: Is this an accurate way to use the dot in the make_future_dataframe section? `make_future_dataframe(prophet(.[which(weekdays(.$ds) != 'Saturday' | weekdays(.$ds) != 'Sunday')`?

Comment: following up on this as weekends are still appearing in output

Comment: made edit to make it correct